# Verilog code if else with localparam

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

What does the Verilog `localparam` `X` code below mean? From my understanding it is as follows:

```
if(y==4)      X = +64;
else if(Y==3) X = +32;
else if(Y==2) X = +16;
else if(Y==1) X = +8;
else if(Y==0) X = +4;
else          X = +2;
```

Is this correct? If so, another thing that doesn't make sense to me is the '+' after the '=' sign, e.g., (X = +2)? Is this something unique to `localparam` variables?

```
localparam  X = (Y==4) ? +64 :
                (Y==3) ? +32 :
                (Y==2) ? +16 :
                (Y==1) ? +8  :
                (Y==0) ? +4  :
                         +2  ;
```

Comment: Your understanding of the conditional operator is correct. The unary `+` can be omitted. It is not unique to `localparam`, it can be anywhere.

Comment: Is there any reason why designers would use the '+' ?

Comment: Could be multiple reasons or no reason at all :) For example it could be a remnant of some longer code involving negative numbers as well, so the `+`s were added for visual consistency.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the `localparam` statement is logically equivalent to the `if/else` pseudocode you showed.  The statement uses the conditional operator which has precedence like your `if/else`.

The `+` signs are unnecessary in the code.  The code behaves the same as if they were not there.  Perhaps someone copy-and-pasted more complicated code (with expressions like `A+2`) and forgot to simplify it. A simpler way to write it is:

```
localparam  X = (Y==4) ? 64 :
                (Y==3) ? 32 :
                (Y==2) ? 16 :
                (Y==1) ? 8  :
                (Y==0) ? 4  :
                         2  ;
```

Answer (score 0):

The conditional operator `?:` is an expression that behaves similar to an `if/else` conditional branching procedural statement as you observed. It can be used in places where is is not practical to use procedural statements. A `parameter/localparam` must be assigned using an expression. You could wrap the `if/else` in a constant function, but the conditional operator is a convenience. If you were making assignments to a variable, a procedural `case` statement would be much clearer.

The unary `+` operator has no purpose other than symmetry with the unary `-` operator. In can make the intent of the code more clear if you have a mix of positive and negative numbers.